# php mod_security find currently logged in user?

Tags: php, mod-security

Can mod_security output whom the currently logged in user is  ?

I've got is set with `SecAuditLogParts ABIZ` which shows what has been changed on a form submission, but I'd like to know who changed it.

The output from `A` shows the IP Address they have come from, but it would be nice to know who they logged in as.

Thanks

Comment: No. Use your controller to get the info ... mod_security is a server-module (if you don't use a server auth e.g. mod_auth apache don't know the logged user)